# big data - where does the data come from?

Tags: hadoop, twitter, bigdata

This might seem like an inane question but with all the buzz about big data I was curious as to how the typical datasets used in big data are sourced? Twitter keywords seem to be a common source - but what are the origins of the huge twitter feed files that get analysed? I saw an example where there was an analysis of election related words like Obama and Romney..has someone queried the Twitter API and downloaded effectively several terabytes of Tweets? Does Twitter even want people hitting their servers that hard? Or is this data already 'owned' by the companies doing the analytics. It might sound an odd scenario but most of the articles I have seen are fuzzy about these basic physical steps. Any links to good articles or tutorials that address these fundamental issues would be most appreciated

Comment: Often, it's your own data, data you're interested in parsing and converting into information.

Comment: Hi visit [140dev](http://140dev.com) for get thousands of tweets/min and display them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some ideas to get sources of Big Data:

- As you pointed [Twitter](https://twitter.com/) is a great place to grab data and there's a lot of useful analysis to do. If you're taking [the online course about Data Science](https://www.coursera.org/course/datasci) one of the assignments is actually how to get live data from Twitter to analyze so I would recommend you take a look at [this assignment](https://class.coursera.org/datasci-001/assignment/view?assignment_id=3) as the process of getting live Twitter data is very detailed. You could let the live stream run for days and it would probably generate Gigabytes worth of data the longer it runs.
- If you have a website you could get web server logs. It might not be a lot if it's a small website, but for large websites who see a lot of traffic this is a huge source of data. Think about what you could do if you had StackOverflow web server logs...
- Oceanographic data which you can find at [Marinexplore](http://marinexplore.org/), they have some huge datasets available that you can download and analyze yourself if you want to analyze ocean data.
- Web crawling data, for example used by search engines. You can see some open data coming from web crawl at [Common Crawl](http://commoncrawl.org/) which is already on Amazon S3 so ready to get your Hadoop jobs running on it ! You could also get data from Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download).
- Genomic data is now available on a very large scale and you can find genome data on [the 1000 genomes project](http://www.1000genomes.org/) via FTP.
- ...

More generally I would advise you look at [Amazon AWS datasets](http://aws.amazon.com/datasets) which has a bunch of big datasets on various topics if you're not just looking at Twitter but Big Data in a more general context.

Answer (score 0):

Most businesses get their social data from [Twitter Certified](https://dev.twitter.com/programs/twitter-certified-products/products#Certified-Data-Products) data partners such as [Gnip](http://gnip.com).

Note: I work for Gnip.